# Cannot access web pages using crawlers after removing index.php from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have removed index.php from my application URL as presented around the web. But I have a weird problem afterwards.

I can access the website using browser like this... `http://www.oakquotes.com/quotes/author/etc-etc` (notice the lack of index.php) but when I try to access the same URL using a crawler then I get forbidden 403 http error.

Here is the robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Allow:/quotes/topic
Allow:/quotes/author
Disallow:

Sitemap: http://www.oakquotes.com/Sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.oakquotes.com/author_sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.oakquotes.com/topic_sitemap.xml
```

I think the culprit is the .htaccess rule that I have written to remove index.php from the URL. Here is the code for htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
    #  Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|Sitemap\.xml|topic_sitemap\.xml|author_sitemap\.xml|search\.html|style|js|system|application|quotes/authors|quotes/topic|application/controllers|application/views)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Am I missing a step? Please help me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: What does the logs say when you get 403 error?

Comment: * Are you sure the crawler is using a Host header?
* Was the crawler able to access the site previously?
* What do the access and error logs say?
* Does the crawler give any more detail about the response it's getting?

Comment: yes, it says foorbidden 403 in http status of the response... logs dont show anything pirticular... i think its related to some issue with url rewriting...

Comment: Test that theory for us and post the results please :) Comment out all the rewrites in your htaccess file, remove the robots.txt file and try the crawler. Then restore the robots.txt and try it. If that still works, restore the htaccess and try it again. If it breaks at that point, it's probably something in the htaccess file and we can go from there. If it's broken even with no htaccess file and no robots.txt then it has to be something else.

Comment: Make sure you're telling your crawler to follow redirects. If you do not, the default page will never be returned.

Comment: try this: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

With a regular Browser, you also get an 403 error. The reason why a website is displayed is the following:

A basic authentication will always return an 403 error. On most servers, a global rule for ErrorDocument 403 is defined like 403.html. If a 403 error is triggered, the server will internally look for the error document 403.html. This document not exists and your RewriteRule matches and the server returns the rendered index.php page. This is why you see an webpage, even though it returned an 403 error. Even more complex, because an 403.html site not exist, an 404 (page not found) is triggered by looking up the 403.html site. That's the problem with global defined ErrorDocuments. An error 500 will trigger an 404 error because to 500.html is defined.

Try to define your one ErrorDocument handling in your .htaccess and you'll see the difference.

```
ErrorDocument 403 "Access denied"
```

This rule will print an error message if an error 403 is triggered and will stop the rendering of index.php